# Unexpected throughput with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a table in DDB with site_id as my hash key and person_id as the range key. There are another 6-8 columns on this table with numeric statistics about this person (e.g. times seen, last log in etc). This table has data for about 10 sites and 20 million rows (this is only used as a proof of concept now - the production table will have much bigger numbers).

I m trying to retrieve all person_ids for a given site where time_seen > 10. So I m doing a query using the hashkey and enter the time_seen > 10 as a criterion. This will result to a few thousand entries which I expected to get pretty much instantly. My test harness runs in AWS on the same region.

The read capacity on this table is 100 units. The results I m getting are attached.

[image]

For some reason I m hitting the limits. Given the only two limits I m aware of are the max data size returned. I m only returning 32 bytes per row (so approx 100KB per result) so no chance this is the case. The time as you see doesnt hit the 5 sec limit either. So why cant I get my results faster?

Results are retrieved in a single thread from C#.

Thanks

Comment: A few things to consider: (1) when you run a Query operation, the RCU consumed relates to the amount of data *processed*, not *returned* (ie, restricting which attributes you *return* won't reduce the amount of RCU consumed; it's counting the full item size, including those 6-8 extra columns); (2) when you add the restriction time_seen > 10, that won't reduce the amount of RCU consumed either -- that's a filter, which is applied *after* your data has been *read* (which is what triggers RCU consumption);

Comment: Thanks Bruno - That certainly clarifies a few things. This leaves me pretty disappointed really. I thought that this query would be a piece of cake for DDB (as discussed we are evaluating the feasibility at this stage). thx

Comment: A more in-depth analysis would definitely require more knowledge about your specific scenario. But apparently you *can* design your DynamoDB table in such a way that the query you mention would be *piece of cake*. I recommend you investigate a bit on *Local Secondary Indexes* and *Global Secondary Indexes*, particularly this last one. You can create these "separate" indexes and only project a few attributes. By doing so, and querying on the index instead of on the main table, the amount of data read and processed by the query could be only what's been projected!